# Python different class parameters

Tags: python, class, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a PointND class, that represents a point in N-dimensional space. I want to be able to give it a list of as an input: `PointND([1,2,3,4])`, and give it a list of inputs: `PointND(1, 2, 3, 4)`. Is there even a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: You'd have to use something like `*args` and check the input type, e.g. `if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], list): ... # handle list input` and `else: ` assume `args` are individual integers.

Comment: Honestly, you probably *shouldn't* do this, just accept `*args` and it is up to the *caller* to use `PointND(*some_list)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The standard `max()` and `min()` functions work like this. It avoids having to create an unnecessary list like `max([a, b])` when you just want to get the max of 2 variables.

Comment: @Barmar the benefit of the way `min` and `max` work is not that you don't have to create a list (accepting `*args` provides that benefit too) but that if you have an iterable you don't have to unpack it... this may save memory if the iterable produces a lot of values (since I assume min/max can discard all but the current min/max as it iterates through... whereas if you unpack it you have materialised all the values into vars)

Comment: @Anentropic It's helpful for both situations. In any case, the same considerations may apply to the OP's function.